# Not able to enter data in CK Editor with Cypress

Tags: automation, cypress

Below solution worked me till chrome version 70, Now 70+ I'm getting error
`CypressError: Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: 'p:eq(0)', but never found it. Queried from element: <body.cke_editable.cke_editable_themed.cke_contents_ltr>`

Solution that stopped working now:

```
.then(function ($iframe) {
 const $body = $iframe.contents().find('body')
    cy
    .wrap($body)
    .find('p:eq(0)').type( "test", { force: true })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of CKEditor are you using, and are you using a javascript framework? We enter text into our CKEditor instances within an Angular appliaction using this command and getting expected results:

```
cy.get('parent-element')
.find('[contenteditable=true]')
.type('text')
```

Maybe it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, version: "4.5.5 for CK Editor. Yes i am using cypress with javascript.

Comment: Working for Cypress version 3.4.1 and chrome browser below 70 version but not working for above.